# datastore entity with more than one unique key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This question has already been asked. But my present situation is a bit different, and I am hoping there are now better answers. So here goes:

I need a datastore entity to have two unique keys, one being the primary key.

Will the following suffice? I need that when I make a keys only query for the datastore to understand that I am referring to `keyA`

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenericType.IDENTITY)
  Key keyA;//based on email

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  Key keyB;//randomly generated
  //….other data
}
```

I need the datastore to help enforce the uniqueness of the keys so it is not enough to let `keyB` be a simple field that I manage myself.

Comment: So does the combination of Key A and  Key B also have to be unique?

Comment: incidentally, per my design.

Comment: You already know your answer, the datastore has no built in support for SQL like "unique indexes". @Namphibian will probably tell you to concatenate both "ids" into a unique Key name. Managing yourself the uniqueness of the email property is actually good enough for your case, since you have *zero* risk of having two persons concurrently creating two `UserAccount`s with the same email...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enforce uniqueness yourself.  That is on the non-primary key you'll have to do a look up and see if you get a result.